# Android development setup on Windows

Tags: android

I have php and .net programming experience. 
I want to set up a development system on a windows 7 64 bit PC. I could do with database usage at a later date. I want to do it as hard coding not use software that you just drag and drop objects to play games.

I have already downloaded and installed jdk-8u20-windows-x64.exe
What do I need to do next and in what if any order.

Comment: Why did you not Google this? There are thousands of tutorials on this including some from Google themselves.

Comment: Did you try Google's developer site?

Answer (score 0):

Get your Android SDK and Eclipse IDE here

> https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

As this is not a programming question please use [Google Search](http://www.google.com/) or a source specific to your problem next time.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple really. I would suggest using Android Studio, which can be found here :

[Download Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)

It says it's a beta version but I have (and I'm not the only one) been using it for production without issues for months now. It's really a question of preference but as far as I'm concerned, I found my productivity to be much higher on Android Studio than it was using Eclipse.

Once it is installed, find the SDK manager and download the latest SDK version, build tools and other things you may need (such as the USB driver for debugging, the support library, ...) :

[image: SDK MANAGER]

I highly recommend you go through [the training on the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html) page to start getting used to your new toys :-)